# regex positive lookahead with if/else condition

Tags: regex, pcre

I am trying to write an regular expression that would check if a pattern exists and, if it does, matches everything following it, and if (and only if) it does not, matches everything after another pattern.

example lines:

```
http://example.com/contact
www.example.com/contact
http://www.example.com/contact
```

expected output in all 3 cases: `example`

Here is the regular expression I expected would do the job:

```
(?(?<=www\.).+|(?<=http:\/\/).+)(?=\.com)
```

which I assumed would:

1. check if "www." is to be found
2. if yes, would match everything following it
3. if not, match everything following "http://"
4. restrict match to everything before the occurrence of ".com "

For the first two lines, the expression worked well, but in the third line `www.example` is matched instead of just `example`. Does this mean that for some reason the `else` command is executed although the `if` condition is met?

How can I change the above expression so that it only does the `http//` lookahead if the `www.` part was not found?

Comment: In what language/tool are you using your regex?  It would also help to show the expected matches for each of the three input lines.

Comment: @h-man Why don't march regardless if `www.` exists and start always from `http` then you for whatever reason you are doing this you can add www. later or just normalize the string...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Converting my comment to answer.

You may use this regex:

```
^(?:https?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)\K\S+?(?=\.com(?:/|$))
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t8AS5S/2/)

**RegEx Description:**

- `^`: Start
- `(?:https?://(?:www\.)?|www\.)`: Match `http://www.` or `http://` or (`https`)
- `\K`: Reset matched information
- `\S+?`: Match 1+ non-space characters (lazy)
- `(?=\.com(?:/|$))`: Using lookahead assert that we have `.com` or end of line ahead